# Downvoting because of something that "could" be added to code to make it break

Tags: discussion, answers, downvotes

I'm relatively new to actively participating at SO so please forgive me if my question seems obsolete.

I just had a discussion in the comments to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42610482/7571258) about a reason to downvote.

Downvoter argues that the example code I gave *could* be easily modified by someone to make it break.

I don't really see how that fits into [valid reasons for downvote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down). I argued that you have to judge the code *as is*, not for the sheer possibility of someone copy-pasting and modifying it to make it break unwantedly. After all, this isn't codereview.stackexchange.com.

So what do you think, valid reason for downvote or not?

Comment: I don't know the language so I can't judge the code itself, but the reason given by the voter sounds fairly reasonable to me. It's ok to downvote code that works, but encourages bad practices (if that's really the case here).

Comment: Sure, this isn't CodeReview, but it doesn't mean that posting code very easily breakable is recommended. If there is a bad practice here, surely there must be a proper way to do the same thing; how about editing with it?

Comment: "very easily breakable" seems to be quite opinion-based because it depends on the experience level of the people reviewing or using the code, but I think I have to accept the fact that people of any level are using SO. So we should make our answers as "idiot-proof" (sorry) as possible.

Comment: I can agree with both you and IInspectable regarding this matter. I don't fully know the language either (I have used it a little bit), however to this point I mostly agree with that there _doesn't seem_ to be any better way of stopping the programmer from putting code in-between other than to write a comment about it. All code can be made broken by changing it just enough, and you can't really stop anyone from doing whatever they want with your code.

Comment: As far as `GetLastError()`, you can definitely not stop anyone from putting anything in-between. Nor can Microsoft in their documentation examples.

Comment: After looking through the edits and seeing your first code snippet I understand what IInspectable meant. However your latest version seems much better!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A valid reason to downvote - which also shows up if you hover the downvote button - is: "This answer is not useful".

If someone believes that it isn't - in this case because they say that the code might easily lead to problems at a later point in time if one is not careful - they have a valid reason to downvote, because they believe that code like this should not be used.

This user even gave a very extensive explanation for why they downvoted which they are not forced to do either, showing you what they think should be changed about the implementation.

Even correct answers can sometimes be downvoted, purely based on the fact that someone might not find it useful, which is again a valid reason for a downvote.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, I get the point and updated my answer. Code may feel "safe" from one's own point of view, but that's not necessarily true for others, especially beginners who tend to copy-paste without much thinking.